# Are sympathy/enthusiasm upvotes legitimate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854462/build-a-really-simple-ocr-or-speech-recognition-software

I agree with everyone that the kid is awesome.

I *disagree* that this is sufficient reason to upvote (but wouldn't downvote, either).

I don't believe it's a good SO question for a variety of reasons; am I off-base here? Is supporting the poster (age, location, chutzpah (oh the irony... or is it Irany?), and so on) reason enough?

The question boils down to this:

> 1 - How can I build my own OCR engine? ( Are there any tutorials or pointers you can give me )
>
> 2 - How to build a speech recognition engine?

Comment: *Aaaaaand* the post is closed.

Comment: Personally, upvoting for saying that they have "poor English skills" isn't the best idea -- if that guaranteed upvotes I'd create a new account, say I was from a traditionally non-English speaking poor country and write in the post "sorry my English is poor, I'm only 16". Not to say that if the user's truthful that's a bad thing, but internet users can lie about a lot of things ;)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I'm sure the OP is being honest, and I'd go out of my way to help him out, I'm just not sure that SO is the best place for him to *start* this endeavor.

Comment: @DaveNewton: definitely agree, SO isn't really the right place for such conceptual ideas -- I just made a note about whether this is sufficient reason to upvote because you'd mentioned that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the votes target the post, not the user, **all** votes are legitimate.

Everyone is free to vote how they please within those (very loose) constraints.

It sounds as if you should vote to close that questions instead, as external tool, library and resource requests are off-topic.

The other thing you can do is comment on the post to communicate with the sympathy voters, which you already did. And with that kind of vote count, the post is *bound* to get more attention anyway, and I'm sure the post will end up closed eventually anyway.

Last but not least, if a post like that doesn't get attention from more level-headed voters (and close voters), you can always mention it in a chat room to discuss it.

Comment: IMO these votes don't; I believe if the age and country were unknown it would be closed and down-voted in heartbeats. I did vote to close, I'm just curious if I *should*.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I quite agree with your sentiment, I added my own close vote. *However*, we still cannot set anything more than guidelines on what votes mean.

Comment: @DaveNewton: for what it's worth, I addressed the 'you are 16, your english is fine, have a +1' comments directly; we can always try to influence the voting by pointing out that a post score is supposed to reflect the quality (which was lacking).